# combine row for each Unique value based on datetime

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table with three column

```
TICKET_ID   ASSIGN  ASSIGN_DATE
5692    ASSIGN-5    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000
5740    ASSIGN-5    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000
5741    ASSIGN-5    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000
5742    ASSIGN-5    2013-07-17 10:40:15.000
5742    ASSIGN-4    2013-07-17 19:37:09.000
```

I need to combine `ASSIGN` row to one row for each `TICKET_ID` based on datetime  ascending result should be like this

```
TICKET_ID   ASSIGN  
5692    ASSIGN-5    
5740    ASSIGN-5    
5741    ASSIGN-5    
5742    ASSIGN-4 ASSIGN-5
```

how can I build the result ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
WITH SampleData(TICKET_ID, ASSIGN, ASSIGN_DATE) AS(
    SELECT 5692, 'ASSIGN-5', CAST('2013-07-17 19:37:09.000' AS DATETIME) UNION ALL
    SELECT 5740, 'ASSIGN-5', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5741, 'ASSIGN-5', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5742, 'ASSIGN-5', '2013-07-17 10:40:15.000' UNION ALL
    SELECT 5742, 'ASSIGN-4', '2013-07-17 19:37:09.000'
)
SELECT
    TICKET_ID,
    ASSIGN = STUFF((
        SELECT ' ' + ASSIGN
        FROM SampleData
        WHERE TICKET_ID = sd.TICKET_ID
        ORDER BY ASSIGN_DATE ASC
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'VARCHAR(MAX)'
    ), 1, 1, '')
FROM SampleData sd
GROUP BY sd.TICKET_ID
```

Read this [**article**](http://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation) by Aaron Bertrand for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the Required Result Set  .. given two solution first is simply join two table on the basis of ticket id ,  2nd join on the basis of Assign row it will give 13 rows

```html
----------1st-------------------

Select T.*,A.* from Tikets T with(nolock)
join
Assignement A with(nolock)
on a.TICKET_ID = t.TICKET_ID
order by t.ASSIGN_DATE

-----------2nd-----------------

Select T.*,A.* from Tikets T with(nolock)
join
Assignement A with(nolock)
on a.ASSIGN like t.ASSIGN +'%' 
order by t.ASSIGN_DATE
```

[enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6)

Thanks